# Why is JTree leaf icon replaced by "bullets"?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I did some package and jar refactoring in my application and now I have several look&feel issues. 
- The one which is easier to explain is that in JTree (embedded within a JXTreeTable), I no longer have "leaf" (file) icon but gray bullet instead...
- Another one is that the default font in TextArea became 'Courier', I hade to force it to a normal font in UIManager to go back to normal...

Has anyone seen this issue already and knows why it happens and how to fix it ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely one of the jars is changing (or is no longer changing) the look and feel of the application. Sounds like you went from the Java look and feel to the "Windows Default" Look and feel. You can try setting the look and feel yourself and see if you can get the desired results.

If it is just the leaf icon that is the problem and you want to work around it, you can change the icon to any image: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display.